# There is a die with two white faces, 1 blue, 2 red and 1 green; we roll it until we get the blue one. Let X denote the number of rolls.

Tags: probability

$(a)$ X has the geometric distribution $g(\frac{1}{5})$

---

$(b)$ $S_X= N ∪ {0}$

---

(c) $F_X(1) = \frac{1}{5}$

---

$(d) P(X > 6|X > 2) ≥ P(X > 4)$

---

$(e) P(X ≤ 5) <\frac{8}{9}$

### Is it true or not?

$(a)$ - I think the geometric distriution is $\frac{1}{6}$
$(b)$ - I think it should be $S_X= N$
$(c)$ - ---------------------
$(d)$ - From the reliability theory I got $P(X>6|X>2)=P(X>4)$ so it's $≥$ $P(X>4)$

$(e)$ - I wanted to use Poisson distribution and wrote a formula: $$\sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}e^{-\lambda}$$, where $\lambda = np$, $n=6^{i}$, $p=\frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Geometric distribution counting the *number of trials needed*, equipped with parameter $p=\frac16$ (preassuming that the die is unbiased).

b) It is for sure that $X$ can take only positive integers as value and that for every positive integer $n$ we have: $$P(X=n)=\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac16\right)>0$$So as support the set of positive integers is a natural choice.

c) $F_X(1)=P(X\leq1)=P(X=1)=\frac16$

d) The distribution of $X$ under condition $X>2$ (i.e. we start with two failures) is the same as the distribution of $2+Y$ where $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$.

So: $$P(X>6\mid X>2)=P(2+Y>6)=P(Y>4)=P(X>4)$$

e) Here $P(X\leq n)=1-P(X>n)=1-\left(\frac56\right)^n$ so we must check here whether the statement $1-\left(\frac56\right)^n<\frac89$ is true or not for $n=5$.

Comment: Are my methods in $d)$ and $e)$ correct?

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "reliability theory" so cannot judge about d). The method used in e) I would call wrong, because there is no need at all to go for an approximation using Poisson.